# Watch for binding changes in an Angular 1.5.3 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller that fetches data to populate a large dropdown:

```
MySrvc.getData()
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.someData = response.data;
    });
```

I also have a component that is instantiated and defined as such..

```
<my-component foo='someData'></my-component>

angular.module('mod').component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
        foo: '<'
    },
    controller: function() {

    }
});
```

`ngOptions` dictates that you must have an `ngModel` set as well. I would like the first element of the array to be the selected object. `this.selectedElement = this.foo[0]`. Problem is, I can't actually write this line of code until I know the binding has been updated.

I can't use `scope.$watch` in a component and `this.$onChanges` doesn't seem to be working either. Any ideas?

Comment: You must have at least angular 1.5.3 to use `$onChanges`. But then it should work with `this.$onChanges = function(){...}`

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach Oh hmm, our minified version is different than our non-minified version. 

Going to fix this and then update.

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach That was it. Works perfectly. Feel free to submit as an answer and I'll submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have at least angular `1.5.3` to use `$onChanges`. But then you can use it like that

```
controller: function() {
     this.$onChanges = function(){
         // your stuff
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem with `ng-if`

```
<my-component ng-if="someData" foo='someData'></my-component>
```

if you add `ng-if` in your element the directive render after the data has come

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a watcher on `this.foo` you can use `$scope.$watch` function. It can accept a function as its first argument, so you can watch a particular variable.

try :

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return this.foo;
},true);
```